# Ant: How to include library in javadoc?

Tags: java, ant

I have made an Ant build file for my Java project. I'm using the matlabcontrol library, i.e. I have the following files:

```
lib: matlabcontrol-4.1.0.jar
lib/src: matlabcontrol-4.1.0-sources.jar
lib/docs: matlabcontrol-4.1.0-javadoc.jar
```

I have two questions regarding my build file:

```
<path id="project-classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*.jar" />
</path>
```

Will this also include the source and javadoc file? Of course I don't want to include them.

Second, I'm creating the javadoc with the following code:

```
<target name="docs" depends="clean docs, compile">
    <mkdir dir="${docs.dir}" />
    <javadoc packagenames="src" sourcepath="${src.dir}" destdir="${docs.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
            <include name="**" />
        </fileset>
    </javadoc>
</target>
```

Is there a possibility to also include the javadoc and sources of the matlabcontrol library or is this usually not done?